# How to pass jvm options / Procfile in Elastic Beanstalk Java SE Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Spring Boot application (a "war" file) on Elastic Beanstalk Java SE (Java 8) but would like to pass jvm options such as heap size. I created a Procfile with the following content:

```
web: java -jar application.jar -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M
```

Unfortunately Beanstalk does not consider this setting and still starts application without the mentioned jvm options.
Please suggest a way to pass jvm options where a war file needs to be deployed on Java SE Platform.

Comment: Is the `Procfile` in the root folder of your deployment bundle?

Comment: Procfile is in the root folder, exactly at the same level where .ebextensions are present. In the directory `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource` I can see the content extracted from the war file I upload and deploy. The content contains .ebextenions folder, Procfile both

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in the past, and solved by deploying a zip file containing both the application jar and the Procfile, instead of putting the Procfile inside the jar.

Something like this:

```
zip -r application.zip application.jar Procfile
eb deploy
```

In the file .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml specify the file to upload:

```
deploy:
  artifact: application.zip
```